# Best Distortion, Clipping, Overmodulation Fixing Plug-in?

Tags: distortion, clipping, fix, plug-in

I'm about to mix a few events where the podium mic was recorded somehow with clipping happening. It's pretty horrendous. But, I'm stuck with it and being asked to fix it.

I've got X-Crackle, but what else do you guys use to handle clipping and distortion?

BF Essentials Clip Removal doesn't work most of the time.

Curious to what you guys use?

Thanks!

- Ryan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've seen a tutorial for Izotope Rx that I remember being pretty amazing. Don't have the link handy…

Comment: Ah - You're quick to the draw. 15 seconds with an answer. Thanks a bunch! I've got the demo, haven't tried the clip removal part of it, yet.

Comment: Yeah, I remember being really amazed by the tutorial. I don't own it yet, but it really should be in everyone's arsenal.

Comment: Well. RX2 was just announced!

Comment: @Hector oh that's exciting. 

Answer (score 3):

I had the worst archival footage, it was all clipped to the point where the waveform was literally flat! Izotope RX's Declipper worked wonders to help smoothen things out. I also used it on an actor's scream, which was badly distorted, and it helped a lot.

Answer (score 3):

+1 for iZotope RX. It's an excellent tool! That and Spectral Analyzer are worth the money alone for the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I've used both of those in the past, and they're pretty good. The Sonnox version is a good one as well.

You might want to try an expander too, to smooth out those squared off peaks/troughs.

Comment: Thanks Shaun! How would you set the expander?

Comment: Honestly, not really sure...never tried it myself. Gonna have to do that one of these days. Some of those drag race recordings I did recently might be good test subjects. Damn those things are loud! lol

Answer (score 1):

+1 On the RX... used it on a Forensic recovery from an answering machine tape- did an amazing job on digging a voice out of massive distortion. Another trick I've used is to feed the signal to a tape emulator plug-in. You can use it to "round off" the hard clip to a softer less nasty sound.

Answer (score 1):

Another vote for RX! Just got RX 2 myself and it's amazing.